# Repository.Stage("*") throws an ObjectDisposedException

Tags: c#, git, libgit2sharp

I stage all files under the git repository for commit, commit the changes, then check for the changes and ammend the commit, changing its message. Take a look at my code:

```
if (this.isRepoInit) // Check if the repository has been initialized successfully
        {
            using (Repository repo = repository)
            {
                // Stage all files
                repo.Stage("*");

                // Setup the commit author
                Signature author = new Signature(this.userData.AuthorName, this.userData.AuthorEmail, DateTime.UtcNow);
                Commit currCommit = repo.Commit("Temporary commit message", author);


                // Write our commit message
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                Tree commitTree = repo.Head.Tip.Tree;
                Tree parentCommitTree = repo.Head.Tip.Parents.Single().Tree;

                TreeChanges changes = repo.Diff.Compare<TreeChanges>(parentCommitTree, commitTree);
                if (changes.Count() > 0)
                {
                    string pluralFile = "file";
                    string pluralInsertion = "insertion";
                    string pluralDeletion = "deletion";
                    if (changes.Count() != 1) pluralFile = "files";
                    if (changes.Added.Count() != 1) pluralInsertion = "insertions";
                    if (changes.Deleted.Count() != 1) pluralDeletion = "deletions";

                    sb.AppendLine(string.Format("{0} {1} changed, {2} {3}(+), {4} {5}(-)",
                        changes.Count(), pluralFile, changes.Added.Count(), pluralInsertion, changes.Deleted.Count(), pluralDeletion));

                    CommitOptions commitOptions = new CommitOptions()
                    {
                        AmendPreviousCommit = true,
                        AllowEmptyCommit = false,
                        PrettifyMessage = true,
                        CommentaryChar = '#'
                    };

                    // Try to commit. If it throws, we log it.
                    try
                    {
                        Commit ammendedCommit = repo.Commit(sb.ToString(), author, commitOptions);
                        Logger.Debug("Committed changes, id: " + ammendedCommit.Sha);
                    }
                    catch (EmptyCommitException)
                    {
                        Logger.Debug("Nothing changed. Skipping commit.");
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Logger.LogError("Error while committing: {0}", e.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I don't know what's happening here. This is the callstack, if anyone wants it:

```
[Edit] ERROR:   An error occurred: ObjectDisposedException at Void SafeHandle.DangerousAddRef(Boolean&): Safe handle has been closed
            CallStack:
               at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.DangerousAddRef(Boolean& success)
               at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.SafeHandleAddRef(SafeHandle pHandle, Boolean& success)
               at LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods.git_diff_index_to_workdir(DiffSafeHandle& diff, RepositorySafeHandle repo, IndexSafeHandle index, GitDiffOptions options)
               at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Proxy.git_diff_index_to_workdir(RepositorySafeHandle repo, IndexSafeHandle index, GitDiffOptions options)
               at LibGit2Sharp.Diff.BuildDiffList(ObjectId oldTreeId, ObjectId newTreeId, TreeComparisonHandleRetriever comparisonHandleRetriever, DiffModifiers diffOptions, IEnumerable`1 paths, ExplicitPathsOptions explicitPathsOptions, CompareOptions compareOptions)
               at LibGit2Sharp.Diff.Compare[T](DiffModifiers diffOptions, IEnumerable`1 paths, ExplicitPathsOptions explicitPathsOptions, CompareOptions compareOptions)
               at LibGit2Sharp.Repository.Stage(IEnumerable`1 paths, StageOptions stageOptions)
```

On the init method of my plugin that is not posted in here, I have a line that defines the variable *repository.* It is: *this.repository = new Repository(Repository.Init(this.gameDirectory));*

Can you guys find any issue with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you wrapping that in a `using`?  This smells like an error.  If you are using this pattern elsewhere, then you would have disposed the repository.

For example, if you are performing:

```
this.repository = new Repository();

using (var repo = repository)
{
    // do something
}

using (var repo = repository)
{
    // do something else
}
```

Then you would get an exception in the second block, because you are trying to use the repository after you have disposed it, by virtue of exiting the first `using` block.

Don't wrap these in `using` blocks.  Just do the work against `this.repository` and dispose that when you are done and your plugin exits.

Alternately, you could make your class `IDisposable` and dispose your repository instance in your `dispose` method.

However you do it, don't call methods on an `IRepository` after you have already disposed it.